# Что за пакеты необходимо установить на Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, rpm

У меня возникла необходимость в установке 2-х пакетов на Linux, но есть одно но — я не знаю их названия.

Мне нужны следующие пакеты:

- Для KDE, который отвечает за отображение запущенных приложений в панели в виде иконок.
- Для управления запущенными окнами. А именно — при наведении окна в правую часть экрана приложение открывается в правой половине экрана, при наведение вверх открывается во весь экран и т.д.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO. Данный вопрос имеет весьма посредственное отношение к [тематике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) данного форума, впредь от подобных вопросов лучше воздержаться.

Answer (score 0):

И то и то звучит как часть стандартной поставки кед, отдельных пакетов отвечающих да это ставить скорей всего не придётся — надо только настроить то что уже есть.

> Для KDE, который отвечает за отображение запущенных приложений в панели в виде иконок.

Если я правильно понял, то нужно просто заменить виджет «Панель задач» на «Панель задач (только значки)», непосредственно она является частью пакета
`plasma-desktop-data`.

> Для управления запущенными окнами. А именно — при наведении окна в правую часть экрана приложение открывается в правой половине экрана, при наведение вверх открывается во весь экран и т.д.

Это часть базового функционала менеджера окон kwin. Дополнительно также ничего устанавливать не нужно... настраивается где-то в глубине его настроек или «Параметров сисемы». Связанный пакет — одноимённый, `kwin`.